# Properties of convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we consider a sequence whose all subsequences
converges to the same limit then can it be claimed that the original sequence also converges to the same limit?
And a mathematical proof will be helpful for the argument.

Comment: Notice that the original sequence is also a subsequence. Therefore, if "all" the subsequences converge to the same limit, then the original sequence also converges to the limit!

Comment: I suspect the statement is not what was intended. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The result is true is a little more generality.

The result is a rather technical one, but is useful for some proofs.

Then $x_n \to L$ **iff** any subsequence contains a further subsequence that converges to $L$.

One direction follow from the definition.

Now suppose the other condition holds. If $x_n$ does not converge to $L$ then there is some $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $|x_{n_k} -L| > \epsilon$ for all $k$. It should be clear that this subsequence cannot contain a further subsequence converging to $L$, hence a contradiction.